# IEEEabrv does not abbreviate the journal names properly

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I would like to use IEEEabrv for my IEEE submission. However, this function does not work at all, as no journal names generated by bibtex are abbreviated. I would like to ask for a solution to this problem. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{etoolbox,iftex}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,nicefrac,amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,enumitem}
\usepackage{scalerel,cmll,trsym}
\usepackage{graphicx,tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float,threeparttable,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xurl}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[justification=centering,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{footnote,subfigure}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makeatletter
\def\th@newremark{\th@remark\thm@headfont{\bfseries}}
\makeatletter

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybib}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read `IEEEabrv.bib`:

> USAGE:
>
> \bibliographystyle{mybstfile}
>
> \bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
>
> where the IEEE titles in the .bib database entries use the strings
>
> defined here. e.g.,
>
> journal = IEEE_J_AC,
>
> to yield "{IEEE} Trans. Automat. Contr."